# Using symbian native API from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, symbian, s60

Is it possible for a Qt program, developed in Qt Creator, to call the symbian S60 native API.

How do I do it? Do I need to download additional headers/lib, or do they come with Qt SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it.

However, you need to make sure, that you've selected 'Symbian target', not 'Simulator', i.e. you cannot call S60 API while building for desktop simulation.

Comment: So I don't need to download anything additionally, all the headers and libs come with Qt SDK?

Comment: @satuon Yes, but make sure that you are using Windows (Linux version doesn't contain needed libs/headers, not sure about OSX one) and make sure you've selected S60 target support in installer.